# Building rsync from git source

Tags: rsync, automake

I am trying to build rsync 1.7.0 from git source.

```
$ autoreconf
$ ./configure
:
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `config.h.in'
```

If I copy `config.h.in` from rsync-1.7.0.tar.gz, `./configure` completes. But `make` fails:

```
$ make
gcc -I. -I. -g -O2 -c rsync.c -o rsync.o
In file included from rsync.c:20:
rsync.h:274:10: fatal error: proto.h: No such file or directory
  274 | #include "proto.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:29: rsync.o] Error 1
```

If I copy `proto.h` from rsync-1.7.0.tar.gz, it works.

How do I create the missing `proto.h` and `config.h.in` that are in the tar file?

Comment: Where are you cloning the git from?

Answer (score 3):

The [`configure.in`](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/blob/v1.7.0/configure.in) file of `rsync` 1.7.0 (an ancient version of `rsync`) was written 23-25 years ago for some older version of `autoconf` that I can't quite pinpoint.  If you try to use more recent releases of GNU autotools, you will have issues creating `configure` and `config.h` correctly.

To properly build the `configure` script and the `config.h` header with more modern GNU autotools, you will need to patch the `configure.in` file manually.  Fortunately, this is quite easy and I'll provide a short diff below, showing exactly what needs to be done:

```
diff --git a/configure.in b/configure.in
index 2d48d001..3905ec5f 100644
--- a/configure.in
+++ b/configure.in
@@ -8,7 +8,7 @@ AC_PROG_INSTALL
 AC_SUBST(SHELL)

 AC_CHECK_PROG(HAVE_REMSH, remsh, 1, 0)
-AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED(HAVE_REMSH, $HAVE_REMSH)
+AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED(HAVE_REMSH, $HAVE_REMSH,[dummy])

 AC_HEADER_DIRENT
 AC_HEADER_TIME
@@ -34,7 +34,7 @@ AC_CHECK_TYPE(ino_t,unsigned)

 echo $ac_n "checking for errno in errno.h... $ac_c"
 AC_TRY_COMPILE([#include <errno.h>],[int i = errno],
-echo yes; AC_DEFINE(HAVE_ERRNO_DECL),
+echo yes; AC_DEFINE(HAVE_ERRNO_DECL,[1],[dummy]),
 echo no)

 AC_FUNC_MEMCMP
@@ -49,20 +49,20 @@ AC_CHECK_FUNCS(memmove getopt_long lchown setlinebuf)
 echo $ac_n "checking for working fnmatch... $ac_c"
 AC_TRY_RUN([#include <fnmatch.h>
 main() { exit(fnmatch("*.o", "x.o", 0) == 0? 0: 1); }],
-echo yes;AC_DEFINE(HAVE_FNMATCH),
+echo yes;AC_DEFINE(HAVE_FNMATCH,[1],[dummy]),
 echo no)

 echo $ac_n "checking for long long... $ac_c"
 AC_TRY_RUN([#include <stdio.h>
 main() { long long x = 1000000000000; char b[20]; sprintf(b,"%lld", x); exit(strcmp("1000000000000", b) == 0? 0: 1); }],
-echo yes;AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LONGLONG),
+echo yes;AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LONGLONG,[1],[dummy]),
 echo no)

 echo $ac_n "checking for utimbuf ... $ac_c"
 AC_TRY_COMPILE([#include <sys/types.h>
 #include <utime.h>],
 [struct utimbuf tbuf;  tbuf.actime = 0; tbuf.modtime = 1; return utime("foo.c",&tbuf);],
-echo yes;AC_DEFINE(HAVE_UTIMBUF),
+echo yes;AC_DEFINE(HAVE_UTIMBUF,[1],[dummy]),
 echo no)

 AC_OUTPUT(Makefile lib/dummy)
```

In short, the `configure.in` file uses `AC_DEFINE` and `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED` with the wrong number of arguments.  Adding dummy arguments fixes this file and `autoconf` 2.69 (and `automake` 1.16) will be able to produce a proper `configure` script and `config.h` header file for you when you run `autoreconf` (as you showed in the question).  This was apparently [fixed in 2001](https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/commit/d4e4cbe105d6e7d9e472eb52e7d33bddc4960d71).

The `proto.h` header is generated by running `make proto`.

The code then compiles on my OpenBSD 6.8 system using the Clang 10.0.1 compiler.

```
$ ./rsync --version
rsync version 1.7.0  protocol version 17
```

Do note that actually using this ancient version of `rsync` is not recommended as it probably contains numerous bugs and security issues fixed in later releases.